# MS Access and Google File Stream

Tags: ms-access

Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question, but with Google's release of "File Stream", does anyone know how this would impact MS Access dbs stored on it?

My "setup" is that I have users that are routinely using an AccessDB that was built for them years ago, and I'm trying to replicate it in MS SQL. Not by my choice, the file is stored by the clients on a Google Drive: Which essentially means that I can only look at the vba and do testing when the clients are not using it. The clients also use Google's sync to access the file.

So my question is two-fold. First, if the clients are looking to move to File Stream and asked how this would impact their ability to use the Access file (I have no idea). Second, will File Stream make it possible to have multiple users on a MS database without causing conflicts or problems? Would I still need to make sure that I have exclusive access to the file while making changes to the vba code?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Over 1k visitors with the same question and updating the description as asked by the person who marked this as -1 (now marked -2 without feedback) but the only question answered is that having multiple users simultaneously isn't sound. What remains is why a single user scenario can cause corruption of the file stored on stream: Compact/repair fails at least when the file is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on experience,  you need to make sure only one person has the database open at a time.  If two people open the database, then changes will not be saved.  Try to find a different solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The MSAccess database engine is fundamentally based on the database primitives provided by the MS file system. Including the record read/write/lock primitives. (Bet you didn't even know that MS operating systems had a native database system!).

Access records and tables are NOT filesystem records and tables, BUT -- the Access database system of records and tables are built on top of the native system of record locking. (The native system doesn't, and never had, any thing smaller than file-level authentication and permissions, so Access built a whole new system on top).

That means that any file system, or any network file system redirector, which doesn't support record locking like the MS file system and the SMB protocol, can't support simultanous multi-user access to an Access database.

I'm not familiar with Google FileStream, but I assume that it's a way to access binary objects using a database API?  Normally that means the API doesn't look inside the binary object: so it can't be locking individual sections of the file for R or W or RW: that means you can't R part of the object while somebody else W a different part: that means you can't share access.   ... and even if File Stream means something different to Google, the chance that they support SMB inside it is slim to none, right?